# How to put events in a Kafka Stream after they have been consumed?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Spring Boot application which consumes from a few Kafka Topics for further processing and eventually push in a DB. It also has Kafka Streams which filter specific types of events from each topic and count how many of each specific type of event has been produced.

I also need to know how many of these events (of each specific types) has been consumed by my application. The Streams work perfectly in counting how many events are in a topic (aka has been produced) but I need the same functionality for consumed messages too. How would I go about implementing something like that?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Spring Boot I would recommend you to enable [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/)
which will automatically collect the client metrics and enable you to easily integrate into your preferred [Monitoring infra](https://micrometer.io/docs) as it supports many of the most used ones.

The count is a metric that is already there so you can easily expose a metric and create a visualization chart with the [count](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters), calculate the rate, etc. Including getting insights per date ranges.

[Spring kafka monitoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/#micrometer)

[Kafka client metrics.](https://kafka.apache.org/30/documentation.html#consumer_monitoring)